# How to use Django Models in Javascript with AngularJS

Tags: javascript, python, angularjs, django

I'm working with django and AngularJS and I want to use my objects I create in Django in my javascript file.

in my models.py (django) I make my object:

```
from django.db import models


class Cashflow(models.Model):
    index = models.FloatField();
    value = models.FloatField();
    date = models.DateField();
```

In my js file I want to use it like:

```
app = angular.module("coco",[]);

app.controller('cocoCtrl',['$scope',function($scope){

$scope.newCashflow = new Cashflow()

$scope.save = function(cashflow){
        $scope.newCashflow.index = cashflow.index;
        $scope.newCashflow.value = cashflow.value;
        $scope.newCashflow.date = cashflow.date;
```

....

but that doesn't work.. Do I forget something? I get no errors or logs but just nothing happens

Comment: You need to serialize it to json using something like Djangorestframework (or write your own if you're feeling adventurous) then have angular make a call to the corresponding url you have set up in your routes

Comment: Just follow the django tutorial first, It will help.

Answer (score 0):

you need to change the model object to Json object by serializing first.

I can show some code for you.

```
results = []
    objects = one_table.object.all()
for i in objects:
   results.append({'field1: i.value1', 'field2': i.value2})

return HttpResponse(json.dumps(results))
```